# How to pick up orbs of light?

Tags: destiny

I see generated Orbs of light being lying on floor, but I can't seem to pick them up when I pass over them, nor is there anything relevant in Destiny keyboard controls. Any ideas how to do this ?

Also, will I be seeing my generated Orbs, esp. when playing single player ?

Thanks!

EDIT: I've seen the "duplicate question", but because none of answers there mentioned that Orbs can only be picked when super-ability meter is low (as mentioned in the only reply to this post), which is what was puzzling me in the first place.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot pick up Orbs of light if your super ability is fully charged (your super ability meter will be yellow if your super ability is fully charged).

Orbs of light that you generate will not appear for you, they can only be seen and collected by other players nearby.